# Is there still heating problem with acer laptop?

Tags: 12.04, overheating

I had previously installed Ubuntu 11.10(or may be some other 11.xx variant I'm not sure) in my Acer apsire 5755g laptop. Which had i5 second generation processor,with 2gb nvidia graphics card and 4gb of RAM. I'm thinking to install the newer version i.e 12.04 , so still   is there that heating problem with Acer laptop?

Note: There is no such heating problem with my laptop while running windows.

Comment: Your heating problem may be related to your graphics cards. The "Optimus" dynamic graphic card switching is not yet supported in Ubuntu. If both the integrated graphic chip and the discrete nvidia card are turned on all the time, it may result in heating and poor battery life.

Comment: Windows tag removed (problem has nothing to do with windows). My Acer does not have and never has had an issue with overheating.

Answer (score 1):

As said, your problem is related to your graphics card. The Optimus dynamic graphics card switching *works great on Ubuntu*. You only have to install **Bumblebee**. Bumblebee allowed manual switching and since version 3 it allows automatic switching

Optimus technology switches off your Nvidia card and use Intel hd graphics in your Core i5 processor when there is no need for high graphics, but switches back to Nvidia when the need comes.

To install bumblebee, do the following in the terminal:

- add bumblebee repository and check updates:

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
  sudo apt-get update
  ```
- check kernel version

  ```
  uname -a
  ```

  example output:

  ```
  Linux  3.5.0-23-generic
  ```
- Install Bumblebee using the proprietary Nvidia driver, change number and suffix of Linux header according to Linux kernel. If your kernel has different number or has `pae` suffix, just add these to Linux headers :

  ```
  sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia linux-headers-3.5.0-23-generic
  ```
- Reboot
- Listen to the fan with less noise
- test installation with this:

  ```
  optirun glxspheres
  ```